# Terminal broken: -bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe

Tags: bash, terminal, nvm

I have recently been trying to install nvm on my mac for hyperledger fabric (following the instructions here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html). Even though I already have it installed, it seems like I needed to put that nvm command into my .bash_profile file (I followed instructions here: https://gist.github.com/Jasondeependra/ff3988b8ce6aa062e8fe3c85fdd284c4)

I put those lines in my .bash_profile and reopened the terminal window, but now it seems to be glitching out, with the top bar continually switching between Termial-bash and Terminal-bash-bash and the console keeps on producing the error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] open your `.bash_profile` and add the following line of code:
>
> ```
> source ~/.bash_profile
> ```

This causes an infinite loop. You should find better instructions.

In the mean time, delete this `source` statement so that the file doesn't keep re-sourcing itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info! I am still pretty new when it comes to command line. But at the moment I cannot use my terminal since it is in that infinite loop. Do you know how else to open/edit the .bash_profile file?

Comment: Do you have access to a graphical editor like TextEdit, KEdit or Notepad? If so, just use that.

Answer (score 0):

I could not edit my .bash_profile file (could not remove the lock) and my terminal was glitching out, so I opened text editor (plain text document), did `Cmd+O`, which opened up to my home directory, did `cmd+shift+>` which showed hidden files, and then moved the current .bash_profile file to the trash. I then restarted went back inside Terminal and did the command `touch .bash_profile` to create a new .bash_profile file.